# How to pass the iterated json data to a method in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi How to pass the iterated json data to a method in javascript?

I have looped over the json data but stuck to pass the iterated json data to the method.Please help me.

Comment: Where is your code? Please edit your question and add them back.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To get a solution for your problem, you must provide what have you tried already. The community can help after that only. For more info, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some samples..otherwise just share you data that you want to iterate.

```js
var dataArray = [1,2,3];

var dataObject = { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}

var arrayOfObjects = [{ x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}, { x: 3, y: 33, z: 333}];


//copy pase any of the block here inside the function based on your data json

//normal array
dataArray.forEach(function(data){
   console.log(data);
});

//Iterate Objects
Object.keys(dataObject).forEach(function(key, value){
   console.log(value, key, 'or',  dataObject[key]);
});

//iterate array of objects
arrayOfObjects.forEach(function(data){
   console.log(data.x, data.y, data.z);
});
```